# Oracle audit trigger code used for multiple tables with different table names

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a requirement to populate an audit column with current timestamp only if there are any updates to the table. Here is the trigger. Trigger works fine

```
create or replace TRIGGER test.Audit_Trigger
BEFORE UPDATE  ON test.TEST_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.column_dtm := current_timestamp;
END;
```

Instead of adding same trigger for every table (around 1000 tables means 1000 triggers) with only change in table name, is there any other better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could write a schema level trigger to do this, but unfortunately Oracle only supports schema level triggers for DDL, not for DML.

You could generate triggers on each table quite easily using dynamic SQL, but assuming your DB version is reasonably recent (9i or later I think), a better alternative might be to talk to your DBA about turning on fine grained auditing for table updates.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm